# Apache 2 / PHP 7 changing content type to text/html: charset=iso-8859-1

Tags: php, apache, character-encoding

I am trying to get all pages on a migrated site to use `iso-8859-1`.  In httpd.conf I have `AddDefaultCharset On`.  One of the pages in question also has `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />` (although I understand with `AddDefaultCharset` that is ignored).

However, in Chrome Dev tools -> Network -> faq.html -> Headers -> Response Headers I still see `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.  Apache is configured to let php files have the .html extension, this file does have a lot of PHP in it (not sure if that matters).

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: UTF-8 is far superior, why the downgrade?

Comment: It's a legacy app (2007ish) and utf-8 was/is causing issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the default charset in `php.ini` too. Check for `default_charset`: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset

The default is UTF8 since PHP 5.6 so you need to force it back to `iso-8859-1`. Just be aware it will be global and will impact any website running on the same setup.

If you want to make this change in your website only, it's probably a better idea to alter the `php.ini` settings from a `.htaccess` file, or by adding something like this in a file that is included at the beginning of all your pages:

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');`

Comment: That was it - thanks.  I set it in php.ini since this legacy app is all by itself on this server.